# OpenGL: Rotating object to point in a given direction

Tags: opengl, graphics, rotation

```
glPushMatrix();
... // Rotation?
drawObject();
glPopMatrix();
```

The function `drawObject()` draws an object with the center at the origin, pointing in the positive x-axis.

How do I rotate the object so it is pointing in the direction `(x,y,z)`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself:

```
glRotatef(atan2(z,x) * 180 / M_PI,0,1,0);
glRotatef(asin(y) * 180 / M_PI,0,0,1);
```